# How to return the positions of first occurrence for (different) duplicated rows in a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

Suppose you have a data frame like the following:

```
dfiris <- rbind(iris[1:5, -5], iris[1:5, -5], iris[1:5, -5], iris[1:5, -5], iris[1:5, -5])
```

Since the first 5 rows are then repeated other 4 times, I would like to efficiently get:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 
1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5
```

The function `duplicate()` does not help me because it only returns TRUE from the second occurrence on of a certain duplicated row.

My (inefficient) solution:

```
apply(dfiris, 1, function(df) {

   which(apply(unique(dfiris), 1, function(df_u) identical(df, df_u)))

})
```

There must be a quicker way to do that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfiris, keep.rownames=TRUE)
print(setkey(dfiris[, list(rn=as.numeric(rn), firstOcc=.I[1]), 
                    by=c(names(dfiris)[-1])], rn))
```

Comment: Thanks. What do you suggest if the data frame has row.names? Example: `pos <- sample(1: nrow(USArrests), 1000, T); usar <- USArrests[pos, ]`. (If it can help, my real purpose is to give the same identification number to each duplicated row, not necessarily the one of the first occurrence).

Comment: I only use the rownames to maintain the order of the data. You can just as well create an index variable for this purpose: `dfiris[, ind := .I]`. Instead of `firstOcc=.I[1])` you could use `group = .GRP`.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try:

```
 library(dplyr)
 left_join(dfiris,mutate(distinct(dfiris), rn=row_number()))
                                                    %>% select(rn)
```